# Column is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am pretty new to Bootstrap coding and have hit a bump in the road. I am putting this code below and I get out a single column instead of a 3*2 grid which is what I thought it would be. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

```
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">

<div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="nounderlineyellow">
        <i class="fa fa-medkit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></br>
        <span style="font-size: x-large;"><br />Trainees</span>
</div>

<div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
    <a href="#" class="nounderlineyellow">
        <i class="fa fa-user-md" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></br>
        <span style="font-size: x-large;">Term Supervisors Clinical Tutors</span>
</div>

<div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
    <a href="#" class="nounderlineyellow">
        <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></br>
        <span style="font-size: x-large;">Examiners</span>
</div>

<div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
    <a href="#" class="nounderlineyellow">
        <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></br>
        <span style="font-size: x-large;">Mentors</span>
</div>

<div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
    <a href="#" class="nounderlineyellow"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></br>
    <span style="font-size: x-large;">Fellows</span>
</div>

<div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
    <a href="#" class="nounderlineyellow"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></br>
    <span style="font-size: x-large;">International Medical Graduates</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What you want to do? Please give your desired output for clearification.

Comment: I would like a 3*2 full screen view that concertinas into a responsive single column on mobile devices. At the moment, the code just produces a single column only.

Comment: You want to see the same output as full screen for mobile screen?

Answer (score 3):

In `Bootstrap`, Every `row` is divided into `12` division. You can use any combination like

```
4+4+4=12
1+2+9=12
6+6=12
------
```

But you have used `4+4+4+4+4+4!=12`. So, you have to think about the dividation of Bootstrap Grid System.

You can read out [this](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp) and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp) for your clarification. Then I think you will be able to solve your problem.

Comment: So if I add a <code><div class="row"></code> at the beginning and the middle it should work yeah?

Comment: Nope may be. Firstly, you have to divide the main row in 3 columns then you can add you row in every row.

Comment: @Mr. Perfectionist: Code work for me. it's Helpful.

Comment: @@Mr. Perfectionist: Any idea of how to get table responsive using Elementor.

Comment: @AsiyaFatima May be you know better than me.